# How do I add two rows in a single cell using html

Tags: html, html-table

I want two rows in single cell.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2ASb.png]

This is the code I have written. I have used `rowspan` to increase the cell width.

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Questions</th>
  <th>sub1</th>
  <th>sub2</th>
  <th>sub3</th>
  <th>sub4</th>
  <th>sub5</th>
  <th>sub6</th>
</tr>
```

I have tried to add the staff but I did not get the way I want.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for? Please update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can add two rows in a single cell using html

```
<tr>
  <th> 
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>sub1</td>
         <td>sub2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>sub3</td>
        <td>sub4</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </th>
 <th rowspan="2">Questions</th>
 <th>sub1</th>
 <th>sub2</th>
 <th>sub3</th>
 <th>sub4</th>
 <th>sub5</th>
 <th>sub6</th>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution @awadhesh